# Using an existing IDB from IDA command line interface

Tags: ida, idapython, automation

Is there any way to use an existing IDB from the IDA command line interface ?

I went through the list of command line switches [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml) but there isn't any related switches.

As I am currently scripting IDA to do some processing based on the same file, I realised I could save some time by reusing the existing IDB, instead of repeatedly deleting and creating another new IDB per iteration. ( -c causes this behavior )

My current command: `idaw.exe -c -A -SC:\someScript.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My current command: `idaw.exe -c -A -SC:\someScript.py`

Remove the `-c` and add the existing IDB file's path:

`idaw.exe -A -SC:\someScript.py C:\existingIdb.idb`

Answer (score 0):

when i need to get some function info on an existing idb i use this see if it helps

```
>cat idc\dumpfun.idc
#include <idc.idc>
static main () {    
        auto fun,ref,funname,fullstr,instr,fpi,fpo;
        Batch(1);
        fun = MinEA();
        fpi = fopen("input.txt","rb");
        instr = readstr(fpi);
        fclose(fpi);
        fpo = fopen("outtext.txt","wb");
        while (fun != -1) {
                fun = NextFunction(fun);
                ref = RfirstB(fun);
                funname = GetFunctionName(fun);
                if( strstr(instr,funname) != -1) {
                        fullstr = form("%x %x %s\n",fun,ref,funname);
                        writestr(fpo,fullstr);    
                }
        }
        fclose(fpo);
        Exit(0);    
}
>echo VirtualQuery > input.txt    
>cat input.txt
VirtualQuery    
>del outtext.txt    
>idag   -Sdumpfun.idc idag.idb    
>cat outtext.txt
5706b8 567b5f VirtualQuery
ffffffff ffffffff
```